# Any way to insert text on page from a query results?

Tags: templates, query

I'm using Woocommerce and its atributes (custom taxonomies). I have some pages which I query this way:

> http://example.com/?tax1=term1&tax2=term2

This query gives me the posts from taxonomy 1 and taxonomy 2 that matches term1 and term2. I'd like to insert some text on these pages. Any way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to insert the text on the fly or write it to the DB permanently? Where do you want to insert it - i.e. do you know how you want to identify the position?

Comment: I'm haven't thought about the database thing. I guess that shouldn't be a problem, since I could edit the text on the DB. So, whatever you think is best.

Position would be in the Woocommerce "products" loop:

 `do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>

<ul> 
   </ul>

   <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); ?>`

Comment: If you had figured out solution yourself please consider adding it as an answer so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, but I was afraid it's not really a good solution. Works, though.

First, I rewrote the query in order to get pretty permalinks:

```
 /*Añadido: Reescribir URL query: "?pa_dispositivo=nombre&pa_marca=nombre"*/
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $feed_rules = array(
        'tipo/(.+)/marca/(.+)'    =>  'index.php?pa_dispositivo='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&pa_marca='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)
        //'(.+)'    =>  'index.php?pa_marca='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
        //'(.+)'    =>  'index.php?pa_dispositivo='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );

/*Fin Añadido*/
```

This gives me something like site.com/name/tax1/name2/tax2.

Then, I modified the file that creates the divs contaning the query results. If the URL is "this" do echo "that":

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //Sacamos la URL y los fragmentos de la URL
    $pieces = explode("/", $uri);
    $uri_prov= $pieces[2];  

    echo "<div class='breadcrumbsBusqueda'>";

    switch ($uri) {

        case "/provincia/".$uri_prov."/":
        echo "<a href='/'>Inicio</a> › ".$uri_prov."</div>TEXT<div class='area_with_sidebar area_left'>";
        break;

        default:        
        echo '<a href="/">Inicio</a> › Esto es lo que hemos encontrado para tu búsqueda: '.get_search_query().'</div><div class="area_with_sidebar area_left">'



        //add as many cases as you need
```

Comment: No need to add (Solved) to title, just mark question as accepted and you're good to go...

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. I'm posting on so many forums that sometimes I get a little confused :-/ Answer accepted.